# What doubts does Sisters Aloysius have?

Tags: plot-explanation, doubt

I remember watching [***Doubt***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0918927/) (2008) and just always thought that Sister Aloysius is such a difficult person to be around and all that she did was just because she just didn't like Father Flynn because of some personal reasons.

Towards the very end of the movie, she breaks down and admits to having doubts.

What exactly is she admitting here?

Does she doubt her judgment of Father Flynn or is she starting to doubt her religious beliefs?

Comment: I had the same question- rewatched-I think her lie, that she called the Father’s previous parish confirmed her suspicions. I think now her Doubt refers to faith.

Answer (score 3):

I interpreted Sister Aloysius as doubting whether Father Flynn was guilty or not. Her passion and condemnation were appropriate if Father Flynn was guilty, and although she couldn't be 100% certain that he was, the idea of his guilt was so reprehensible that should couldn't withhold her judgment while waiting for it to be proved one way or the other.

I suspect the John Patrick Shanley, who wrote the play that the movie is based on, intentionally left the line vague ("I have such doubts!") so the audience would be left uncertain as well.

Answer (score 1):

She might well have doubted her faith. But I think she doubted the way she handled the Father Flynn situation.

In the final scene she makes it clear that he was simply transferred to another school and was not sanctioned in any way. In fact he was given a promotion.

Sister Aloysius thinks he should have been taken further to task. Much further. Because as things stand he can continue to abuse children.

Therein lie her doubts; that she wasn't strong enough, tough enough, diligent enough, thorough enough to take all the steps necessary make sure Flynn never harmed another child even if it caused harm to the church,or in spite of the fact that it would cause harm to the church, because anything short of the steps she did not take will allow abuse not just to proliferate but to do so systemically.

Comment: I definitely think it's what James Sherman said. She had NO doubt of what Father Flynn had done. She stated that over and over again, but I think she had doubt about the church's ability to actually handle the situation and to keep it from happening again.

Comment: Yelling isn't going to make the point salient.  Nothing is certain.  I side with Brett here.